# My Home WiFi Password was given away to a plumber who said he needed it, it then unusually went down for no apparent reason, is this suspicious?

Tags: wifi, router

My home WiFi password was given away by my dad to a plumber who came in saying that he needed the WiFi password for his phone. As soon as he told him the WiFi went down for a few minutes, which I found suspicious. Does the WiFi going down indeed suggest anything suspicious or malicious, and what are the security implications of this?

Finally, I would like to ask, if something malicious were to have happened, what action should I take? Would changing the WiFi password be enough?

Comment: WiFi going down does not need to mean anything malicious.  It can just be a crashing hotspot due to some broken WiFi stack in the connecting device (seen it), it can be that someone tripped over the power cable or similar, it can just be a coincidence in timing, .... But WiFi __not__ going down instead might be related to malicious activity - because if someone wants to use the local WiFi for malicious things it likely needs to keep working.

Comment: It's not unfathomable that the plumber may have done something nefarious, that could cause the wifi to go down.  For example, he may have plugged a raspberry pi into an outlet in the basement or under the sink, which connects to the wifi and runs a TOR hidden service.  If it's a heavily used service, this could be causing disruptions in your wifi service.

Comment: The wifi reboot could've been to clear the log - some devices don't persist the log across reboots. Not sure where you are in the world, however, words can't express how utterly strange this request seems to me - my hackles would be up immediately: I would have to stop myself from laughing loudly in their face, if only to allow it and then monitor this person's activities.

Answer (score 2):

We will have no idea if the disruption is malicious or not; we'd be guessing.

If you feel that something malicious happened:

- change the wifi password immediately
- change the router's admin password
- check all router settings, especially open ports, allowed devices, remote access
- use an app on your phone to physically trace any wifi transmitting device in your home to look for devices that are not your own (these apps are tricky and are not always easy to use)

Comment: What about a simple factory reset?

Comment: @kelalaka sure, but that might cause more disruption to the household than something more precise.